# What sort of time complexity would be required to solve the RSA Factoring Challenge?

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, time-complexity, rsa, big-o

Although the challenge ended a long time ago, I'm kinda bored so I decided to try to factorise some of the numbers.

I initially had an O(n) algorithm, but then, I decided to research big O notation.

Apparently (I could be wrong), O(n) algorithms and O(2n) algorithms basically have the same running time. So do O(n) and O(4n) algorithms. In fact, O(n) and O(cn) algorithms (where c is an integer) essentially have the same running time.

So now, I have an O(8n) algorithm, but it isn't quick enough for 77-bit numbers.

**What sort of time complexity would be required to factorise the first few RSA numbers (in under 5-ish minutes)?**

My O(8n) algorithm:

```
import math

num = int(input())

sq = math.sqrt(num)

if num % 2 == 0:
  print(2, int(num / 2))

elif sq % 1 == sq:
  print(int(sq), int(sq))

else:

  sq = round(sq)

  a = 3
  b = sq + (1 - (sq % 2))

  c = ((b + 1) / 2)
  d = ((b + 1) / 2)
  c -= (1 - (c % 2))
  d += (1 - (d % 2))

  e = ((c + 1) / 2)
  f = ((c + 1) / 2)
  e -= (1 - (e % 2))
  f += (1 - (f % 2))
  g = ((d + 1) / 2) + d
  h = ((d + 1) / 2) + d
  g -= (1 - (g % 2))
  h += (1 - (h % 2))


  while a <= sq and num % a != 0 and b > 2 and num % b != 0 and c <= sq and num % c != 0 and d > 2 and num % d != 0 and e <= sq and num % e != 0 and f > 2 and num % f != 0 and g <= sq and num % g != 0 and h > 2 and num % h != 0:

    a += 2
    b -= 2
    c += 2
    d -= 2
    e += 2
    f -= 2
    g += 2
    h -= 2


  if num % a == 0:
    print(a, int(num / a))
  elif num % b == 0:
    print(b, int(num / b))
  elif num % c == 0:
    print(c, int(num / c))
  elif num % d == 0:
    print(d, int(num / d))
  elif num % e == 0:
    print(e, int(num / e))
  elif num % f == 0:
    print(f, int(num / f))
  elif num % g == 0:
    print(g, int(num / g))
  elif num % h == 0:
    print(h, int(num / h))
```

Comment: First: what is n? Usually it is taken as the number of digits of the number to factor. If this is also your interpretation I would like to see the O(n) algorithm.
Second, O(n) tells you absolutely nothing about the absolute run time. It only tells you how the run time changes in the limit if n varies.

Comment: @Henry 1. n is approximately ((the square root of the RSA number) / 2)     2. You're right, but surely there's a way to determine what sort of time complexity is required?

Comment: For a 40 bit number (i.e. 12 to 13 decimal digits) even one of the most basic algorithms, trial division with small prime numbers (say, less than 3 million) will find the factors in less than a second on modern hardware.

Comment: @Henry Right now, I'm using an online python IDE compiler (repl.it) (as I'm away from my normal workspace) so I don't know if this slows the program down. The 40-bit number I'm trying to factorise is 245710994444403048837841.

Comment: That's not 40 bits, it is 79 bits. PARI/GP finds the factors 375763710997 and 653897615053 practically instantly.

Comment: @Henry Sorry, you're right about the bits (the generator I was using was using **factors of 40 bits** not **generating semiprimes of 40 bits**). I'll post my algorithm in case that helps.

Comment: Trial division will take too long with numbers of this size. You will need something faster. You could try the Multiple Polynomial Quadratic Sieve algorithm.

Comment: @Henry I'm trying a sort of trial division, but I'm using multiple 'counters' to speed up the process as the more 'counters' there are, the more likely it is that the program will end quicker.

Comment: This question isn't really suitable for SO. I guess with some work, it might be acceptable on software engineering, but you need to explain your algorithm, and not expect people to decipher it from your code. OTOH, state-of-the art factorization requires some fairly advanced mathematics, and this just looks like slightly enhanced trial division.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm is poorly-implemented trial division. Throw it away.

Here is my basic prime-number library, using the Sieve of Eratosthenes to enumerate prime numbers, the Miller-Rabin algorithm to recognize primes, and wheel factorization followed by Pollard's rho algorithm to factor composites, which I leave to you to translate to Python:

```
function primes(n)
    i, p, ps, m := 0, 3, [2], n // 2
    sieve := makeArray(0..m-1, True)
    while i < m
        if sieve[i]
            ps := p :: ps # insert at head of list
            for j from (p*p-3)/2 to m step p
                sieve[i] := False
        i, p := i+1, p+2
    return reverse(ps)

function isPrime(n, k=5)
    if n < 2 then return False
    for p in [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29]
        if n % p == 0 then return n == p
    s, d = 0, n-1
    while d % 2 == 0
        s, d = s+1, d/2
    for i from 0 to k
        x = powerMod(randint(2, n-1), d, n)
        if x == 1 or x == n-1 then next i
        for r from 1 to s
            x = (x * x) % n
            if x == 1 then return False
            if x == n-1 then next i
        return False
    return True

function factors(n, limit=10000)
    wheel := [1,2,2,4,2,4,2,4,6,2,6]
    w, f, fs := 0, 2, []
    while f*f <= n and f < limit
        while n % f == 0
            fs, n := f :: fs, n / f
        f, w := f + wheel[w], w+1
        if w = 11 then w = 3
    if n == 1 return fs
    h, t, g, c := 1, 1, 1, 1
    while not isPrime(n)
        repeat
            h := (h*h+c) % n # the hare runs
            h := (h*h+c) % n # twice as fast
            t := (t*t+c) % n # as the tortoise
            g := gcd(t-h, n)
        while g == 1
        if isPrime(g)
            while n % g == 0
                fs, n := g :: fs, n / g
        h, t, g, c := 1, 1, 1, c+1
    return sort(n :: fs)

function powerMod(b, e, m)
    x := 1
    while e > 0
        if e%2 == 1
            x, e := (x*b)%m, e-1
        else b, e := (b*b)%m, e//2
    return x

function gcd(a, b)
    if b == 0 then return a
    return gcd(b, a % b)
```

Properly implemented, that algorithm should factor your 79-bit number nearly instantly.

To factor larger numbers, you will have to work harder. Look up "elliptic curve factorization" and "self-initializing quadratic sieve" to find factoring algorithms that you can implement yourself.

Comment: No offence, but this isn't answering the question I'm asking. I already have this algorithm and have implemented it. I just wanted to know what sort of time complexity would be required.

Comment: Both elliptic curve and quadratic sieve are sub-exponential. Quadratic sieve is *e* to the square root of log *n* log log *n*. Elliptic curve is *e* to the square root of 2 log *p* log log *p*, where *p* is the unknown factor.